# Extrusion along a path-keep y-orientation of profile

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

I want to extrude a modified curve along a spiral path, which still works fine, but I want my profile oriented upright up to the end of the stairs. Right now it tilts - as expected because of the spiral form...I did not find an option when activating the profile...Thx for helps in advance!

TAffi TAsteless

Comment: can you add an image that illustrates your issue?

Comment: from what I guess, just extrude the last point of the spiral with a point that goes a tiny bit in the direction you want the stairs to face. Is the spiral path a bezier or nurbs spline ?